# Inject non-existing property via @Value from .yml file for HashMap

Tags: spring

I've got many .yml files with properties for different projects. Configuration bean is the same for all of them but some of properties might be missing for some reason. The question is how to set default NULL value to field such as HashMap via @Value. So what I'm trying is:

```
    @Value("${property.time:#{null}}")
    private Integer time;

    @Value("#{${property.map:#{null}}}")
    private HashMap<String,String> map;
```

So for first field if property is missing in .yml file then Integer becomes null which is correct.

If there is no map in .yml file I'm trying to set it to null but getting Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [#{null}] @1: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

p.s. Cant use spring boot in project so trying to fix it with spring framework

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default value as follow :

```
@Value("${some.key:10}")
private int myKey;
```

Here it will try to look for the `some.key` value in the corresponding .yml file, if it is missing it will use the default value.

Comment: Trouble is with HashMap